# How to get value of textbox from one form to another form using inheritance in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Let say, I want to get value of textbox from one winform to another with the help of inheritance in vb.net

```
If Form1.TextBox1.Text = "1" Then
    'This is Form2'
    TextBox1.Text = "1"
Else
    TextBox1.Text = "2"
End If
```

Comment: please show codes and what you have done.

Comment: added code. please see

Comment: Inheritance is completely irrelevant to moving data between forms. Why do you think otherwise? What are you actually trying to achieve? Is this an exercise in inheritance or an exercise in moving data?

Comment: Also, please explain exactly how the behaviour of the code you have differs from your expectation. You assistant know how to get text from another form and set text in the current form so what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code below is just for demo. Advised not to do in this way. This is really really bad coding

1. Create two forms; from1 and form2.
2. Add two textboxes and one button.
3. copy the code below.
4. you type in textbox2 and click the button.
5. it will display in form1, if you enter it from form2 and vice versa.

   ```
    // Form1.vb       
   Public Partial Class Form1
   Inherits Form

   Private f2 As Form2

   Public Sub New()
       InitializeComponent()
       f2 = New Form2(Me)
       f2.Show()
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
       f2.setText(textBox2.Text)
   End Sub

   Public Sub setText(ByVal text As String)
       textBox1.Text = text
   End Sub
   End Class

    // Form2.vb
   Public Partial Class Form2
   Inherits Form

   Private f1 As Form1

   Public Sub New(ByVal form As Form1)
       InitializeComponent()
       f1 = form
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
       f1.setText(textBox2.Text)
   End Sub

   Public Sub setText(ByVal text As String)
       textBox1.Text = text
   End Sub
   End Class
   ```

what this code do is create form2 with reference to form1 and call setText which will change text in textbox1 in either form when button click. 
***I repeat never ever do this.*** there you go vb

Comment: Yes, this works but it has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: Please check @jmcilhinney comment for inheritance.